# c# paypal rest api transaction search

Tags: c#, api, rest, paypal, transactions

So I have spent a bit of time reading the PayPal REST API docs. I am struggling to see how I can get a list of completed transactions for a given date range (1 Day).

I have inherited an application that uses a form post method to capture the payment and there is a webservice callback that provides the status of the transaction. The only thing currently captured from the call back is the status and a transaction reference.

I am trying to get a date range of transactions for reconciliation purposes so would appreciate some pointers regarding the API. I have looked at getting single 'sale' using /v1/payments/sale/ but that will only show sales created using the REST API, which is not how it has been created.

My solution is in C#. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE` according to  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/
OR
Just get all responses and use the timestamps to create a range inside C# in which you filter your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the REST API then you have to pass the "**start_time**" and "**end_time**" to filter your result based on the date . You can refer the below link :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#list-payment-resources

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#paging--filtering